# ArrayListMultimap Exception while starting server when using the Endpoints framework - 1.9.56

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I am using Java appengine 1.9.56.   I am including the following endpoints framework 1.0 entries in web.xml

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>services</param-name>
            <param-value>com.veersoft.services.api.VoucherAPI
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/_ah/spi/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

I get the following Exception while starting the server

```
Uncaught exception from servlet
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/appengine/repackaged/com/google/common/collect/ArrayListMultimap
at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService.<init>(SystemService.java:128)
at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.createSystemService(SystemServiceServlet.java:170)
at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.createSystemService(SystemServiceServlet.java:136)
at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.init(SystemServiceServlet.java:59)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:643)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initialize(ServletHolder.java:422)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:892)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:349)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1406)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1368)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:778)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:262)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:522)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppVersionHandlerMap.createHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:244)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppVersionHandlerMap.getHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:182)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:97)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchServletRequest(JavaRuntime.java:650)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchRequest(JavaRuntime.java:612)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:582)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$NullSandboxRequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:776)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:263)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Is this the Java 8 runtime?

Comment: Yes, this is Java 8 runtime

Answer (score 0):

The v1 frameworks are not supported on the Java 8 runtime. If this is an existing application, your options are to downgrade the runtime to Java 7, which you do by specifying in `appengine-web.xml`, or [upgrade to the v2 frameworks](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/legacy/v1/java/migrating). If this is a new app, then you should upgrade to the v2 frameworks.

Comment: I am using 1.9.56.  The release notes for 1.9.57 says that v1 endpoint frameworks wont be supported on java8

Comment: That is a retroactive answer. The v1 frameworks have never been supported on the Java 8 runtime.